# Technical word for fish bones

Tags: single-word-requests

What do we call the bones of a fish other than "fish bone"?

I know their material is cartilage or ossein?

But is there a single noun that describes fish bone?

Like the french word arêtes.

Comment: There might be a technical term, but I don't think there's a single word in common use.

Comment: "fish bones" is already a very short phrase, there's hardly a need for a single word.

Answer (score -1):

There is a single word that means “fish bone”, and that word is… *[fishbone](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/amp/english/fishbone)*.

I looked up the word "fishbone" in several thesauruses and synonym finders, and it appears that there are no other words that mean the same thing.